Proving "if Q is derivable from P, then all sentential interpretations of P->Q are true" from Suppes criterion I
Question.
I have trouble understanding how Patrick Suppes in his "Introduction to logic" derives the important sentence (A2) from another two, (A1) and (CrI).
Introduction.
He uses criterion I:

(Cr1): "Given a set of premises, the rules of logical derivation must permit
to infer ONLY those conclusions which logically follow from the
premises."

He also uses sentence:

(A1): "Q logically follows from P if every sentential interpretation of the implication P→Q is true."

He derives:

(A2):"Q should be derivable from P by use of the rules only if every interpretation of P→Q is true".

My attempt.
It is hard for me to comprehend proofs in natural language. So, I am using  symbolizations.
I use "⇒" to symbolize if-then of the metalanguage and "→" for if-then of the object language. All quantifiers belongs to metalanguage.
I understand criterion I as
$$\forall P,Q [L(P,Q)\Rightarrow\exists R[R(P,Q)]],$$
where R(P,Q) is "Q can be derived from P via rule R",
L(P,Q) is "Q logically follows from P".
I understand (A1) as
$$\forall P,Q [L(P,Q)\Leftarrow\forall x[x \in \operatorname{sInt}(P→Q)\land x=1]],$$
where sInt(P→Q) is "set of all sententional interpretations of P→Q".
I understand (A2) as
$$\forall P,Q [\exists R[R(P,Q)]\Rightarrow\forall x[x \in \operatorname{sInt}(P→Q) \land x=1]].$$
In some other place of the books he writes that "P only if Q" is same "Q→P".
In my understanding, from (CrI) and (A2), we can infer only:
$$\forall P,Q [\exists R[R(P,Q)]⇐\forall x[x \in \operatorname{sInt}(P→Q) \land x=1]].$$
So, for me, the derivation A1+Cr1→A2 seems counter-intuitive.
P.S.  Please keep explanations simple. I am a chemist who has logic as a hobby. There are many things that are very obvious for you and are far from obvious for me. That is because you work a lot with these things and I see them rarely. I have gone through six textbooks on logic with exercises.
Scans.
Criterion I

(A1)

(A2)


$A\implies B$ is true whenever $B$ is true , even if $A$ is false.

Could you explain in more detail? I know all the rules for sentential logic, and it didn't help me to solve this issue. I have been struggling for 2 days with no success.

(A2) is a restatement of (Cr1). The idea is: assume that we have a purported rule FR ("fake" rule) that violates (Cr1), i.e. such that Q is derivable from P with FR but $P \to Q$ is NOT True for every interpretation. This means that there is an intepretation such that $P \to Q$ is False; but by (A1) this means that Q does NOT logically follows from P, contrary to (Cr1).

Could you explain how to derive from sentences "there is a false sentential interpretation of P->Q" and (A1) "Q logically follows from P if every sentential interpretation of the P->Q is true" the sentence that "Q does not follow from P".

See Logical consequence and Tautological consequence for the particular case of propositional logic.

In the Suppes book there is if in the definition. The sentence with definition is marked with a star:" The use of if without 'only if' indicates that a sufficient condition is given, but that no commitment regarding necessity is made"

Correct, because "logical consequence" is based on "every interpretation" and not only the "sentential" ones. Thus, the IFF case will be: "Q logically follows from P iff every  interpretation of $P \to Q$ is true"

(I) IF every sentential interpretation of $P \to Q$ is true, THEN $Q$ logically follows from $P$.
And:
(IV) IF $Q$ is tautologically implied by $P$, THEN $Q$ logically follows from $P$.
By (CI): Given a set of premises, the rules of logical derivation must permit to infer ONLY those conclusions which logically follow from the premises,
we have that a sound set of rules must permit to infer a conclusion $Q$ from premise $P$ only if $Q$ logically follows from $P$, and this in turn means that:

a sound set of rules should allow the derivation of $Q$ from $P$ only if every interpretation of $P \to Q$ is true.

Then apply the note of 7th line page 22: "we obtain a complete [with "IFF"] characterization of logical consequnece by omitting the restriction to sentential interpretations."
